# Spring Quartz simple trigger not firing as expected

Tags: spring, quartz-scheduler

I am having a simple trigger bean which should be fired for every 20min.
For that I am specifying the repeatinterval value in properties file. But my job is getting waked up every minute instead of every 20min.

sample xml

```
<bean id="propertyLoaderJob" 
      class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.MethodInvokingJobDetailFactoryBean">
        <property name="targetObject" ref="propertyloader" />
        <property name="targetMethod" value="propFlagValidator" />
        <property name="concurrent" value="false" />
</bean>
<bean id="propertyLoaderTrigger"
    class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SimpleTriggerBean">        
    <property name="jobDetail" ref="propertyLoaderJob" />
    <property name="repeatInterval" value="${quartz.scheduler.repeatInterval}" />
    <property name="startDelay" value="${quartz.scheduler.startDelay}" />       
</bean>
```

in the properties file I have these fields

```
quartz.scheduler.repeatInterval=1200000
quartz.scheduler.startDelay=1000
```

What could be the possbile reason for this?
Please help.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: in which code section are you pointing to your reference property file?

Comment: Its working fine now.

Comment: you have to state what went wrong and what corrected the problem, otherwise another person having the same problem cannot find the solution

Comment: Should i answer it or have it as a comment?

Comment: you can give an answer or a comment, but an answer is good

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For future reference i am answering.

Along with the mentioned part in my question i forgot to add the below code. That is for actually triggering it:

```
<bean name="nonclusterMode"  class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean">        
    <property name="triggers">
        <list>              
            <ref bean="propertyLoaderTrigger" />            
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Now it is working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Have you specified a property placeholder for this,

***Using Context namespace,***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">
 . . .
 <context:property-placeholder location="quartz.scheduler.properties" />
 . . .
 </beans>
```

---

***or*** ***Adding PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer bean in application context***

```
<bean id="propertyConfigurer" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
 <property name="location">
 <value>classpath:quartz.scheduler.properties</value>
 </property>
</bean>
```

Comment: Yes I have a properties file and many other beans are taking values correctly from that file.

Comment: <bean id="propertyConfigurer"
  class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
<property name="locations">
   <list>
    <value>file:${CLUSTER_HOME}/properties/pacSchedulerEnvironment.properties</value>
   </list>
  </property>               
.................................
CLUSTER_HOME is the environment variable.

Comment: check by setting values to <property name="repeatInterval" value="1200000" />
    <property name="startDelay" value="1000" /> without using property file

Comment: The thing is it is working in my local machine.
But when I deploy in other UNIX machine it is not working. Other cron triggers are working though. That means properties file is getting load properly.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that you are not using any other trigger for the same class/job i.e. propertyLoaderJob. It may have happened that you are using a cron expression as well associated with the same job. It will be great if you can share the complete spring xml file.

Comment: I am afraid i cannot share the whole XML s but I am quite sure I am having only one job in this class. And I have four more different cron jobs pointing to different classes and they are getting waked up properly. Cron expression is also in the properties file.